# Thymeleaf table row click not recognizing js function

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

The onclick event is complaining that the java script function is not defined.

```
<body>
    <div layout:fragment="content" th:remove="tag">
        <div class="container">
            <h6 class="mb-3">Restaurant Order Details</h6>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Order Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Order Details</th>
                        <th scope="col">Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr th:each="order : ${orders}" style="cursor: pointer"
                        th:attr="onclick=|getOrderItems('${order.orderId}')|">
                        <td scope="row" th:text="${order.orderId}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${order.orderDetais}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${order.orderDate}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${order.amount}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">Total</td>
                        <td th:text="${grandTotal}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="mb-4"></div>


        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function getOrderItems(orderId) {
            alert("order details here");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

When I click on the table row I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getOrderItems is not defined
    at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick
```

When I replace getOrderItems with a simple alert instead, the alert is fired. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not the answer you looking for, it's just a suggestion:
In JavaScript, you can actually use the thymeleaf variables like this:

```
var myVar = [[${order.orderId}]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was I declared my `<script>`  outside the `<div layout:fragment="content" th:remove="tag">` tag. Since this is a fragment, thymeleaf only rendered everything within this scope. Putting the script tag inside this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing thymeleaf variable to javascript. You can issue `<script>` outside your  (just above `</body>`) and still pass variable to JS.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var orders = [[${orders}]];
    function getOrderItems(orders) {
        alert("order details here ");
    }
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Then you can call JS method on your html onclick event.

```
<tr th:each="order : ${orders}" style="cursor: pointer"
    th:attr="onclick=|getOrderItems(orders)}')|">
    <td scope="row" th:text="${order.orderId}"></td>
    <td th:text="${order.orderDetais}"></td>
    <td th:text="${order.orderDate}"></td>
    <td th:text="${order.amount}"></td>
</tr>
```

However, I still see a challenge if you wish to pass every single `order` to javascript. I haven't used `<script>` inside the `th:each` loop.

Comment: I did try doing this. However, when the final page was rendered with headers and all, the script was not present in when I viewed the page source.